# DRF APIView - How can I add help text to auto generated form?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am working with Django Rest Framework and using APIView and serializer form to add new data. I want to add some help text to the form as tooltip. Since the form is auto generated, I need some help on how can I add this to the form. I am using ModelSerializer.

This is how my serializer looks like

```py
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        Model = MyModel
        fields = ('id','name', ...)
```

My form fields should have help texts. How can I add them? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Specify `help_text` as  additional keyword argument (see [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments)) instead declaring a serializer field specifying all options that are already in the model field (`unique`, `null`, `max_length` etc.)

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id','name', ...)
        extra_kwargs = {
            'name': {
                'help_text': 'You help text here...'
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

You could add the help text using [**`help_text`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#help_text) argument of serializer field

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(help_text="foo bar")
    class Meta:
        Model = MyModel
        fields = ('id','name', ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add help_text attribute in models.py

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=60, help_text="Your help text here....")
```

[More Info...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.help_text)